# Windows 10 Top bar Color change / registry value?

Tags: windows-10, colors

Edit:
So going through the Personalize option work for focused window
But I would like to change the color when windows aren't focused.
Any idea of the Registry value to tinker with RegEdit ?
Or other method ?

Thanks you

---

I would like to change the color of the Top bar in windows, especially Firefox.
I suppose it should be through Windows since Firefox doesn't have any option I see as "white" or "255", and also because NotePad (and other program) also have their top bar in white.

So to be clear, I'm talking about those:
[my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuuNT.png)

I tried various entry in RegEdit that were in "255 255 255" , mainly what was under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors (or [..]Control Panel\Desktop\Colors) but nothing seems to be the one.

It seems possible since I found a thread here about a similar issue (but related to another part of the windows) where an answer showed a screen with blue top bar, just like that:
[screenshot with top blue bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g8jq.png)

I'm new on Windows 10 so it's a pain in the butt to found back option I was used to on 7.
Any idea to help me pretty please ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Right click on desktop -> select `Personalize` -> select `Colors` on the left -> Scroll down to `Choose your accent color` and select one eg. blue -> scroll down more and tick the check box `Title bars and window borders`.

This will apply your chosen accent color to title bars and as a side effect to borders.

EDIT: unfortunately the color is applied only when window has focus. Unfocused windows still have default eg. white color on title bars.

Comment: Windows 8+ made a great deal of changes to the user's ability to customize File Explorer, so many of the tricks that worked on Windows 7, do not work on Windows 8+.  Which is fine since there are either Windows 8+ specific tricks or one simply uses Settings to make the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, to think it was under my eyes... I feel sad. 

However as you said, it will be the selected color only during focus, if I unfocus the window, it will be back to default
Any idea to change the deffault color ? Maybe the name of the value to change in Reg Edit ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a fairly new version of Windows 10 (since you are new to Windows 10), this can be done with Accent Colors

Start, Settings, Personalization, Colors. Then make sure both Top Bar and Start are selected.

I posted a Screen Shot and you can see that my Accent Color is Blue and all my top bars are blue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't realize it was the "Title bar" option, especially since the bar would still remain white as I'm not focusing the window, as the coment above said.
Do you have a tips or idea how to change the color when the window is Unfocused ? 
Maybe a RegEdit line to check ?
Thanks

Comment: You can select whatever color you wish. See above in the screen shot where I selected Blue. Select what you want. In terms of Unfocussed Apps, it depends on the App. I have Office Apps open, unfocused, and the top bars retain their color. So it all works very well but not 100% perfect. Certainly highly usable.